# Customize the devise signed_up_but_unconfirmed message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Actually I want to customize signed_up_but_unconfirmed message the message is

```
A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account.
```

and I want to add a user email id in the message. I want the following message

```
A message with a confirmation link has been sent to abc@example.com .Please follow the link to activate your account.
```

How do I customize those error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override Devise's `en.yml` [file](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml).

Copy it to `config/locales/devise.en.yml`, find there

```
signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account."
```

and change it to:

```
signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to %{resource.email}. Please follow the link to activate your account."
```

Comment: actually I did this but its not working. Its showing me  `A message with a confirmation link has been sent to %{resource.email}. Please follow the link to activate your account.` .Its not showing actual email address...

Comment: @DeeptiKakade Hm, that's strange.

Comment: Same here. It's not replacing the variable by an actual value.