# Allow devise forgot password reset only after email confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My devise is working property but I want to do something that, the user can't forgot password yet as long as he/she didn't do during the confirmation.

Question: How can I check if the user confirmed the email before they request an forgot password?

NOTE: I tried to sign-up, click the forgot password link, proceed to rails/mailers to choose the reset password link.. It will ask you a new password.. after that signing(assumed you've finished the confirmation) then tried the new password.. it can now login

Comment: you can provide client side validation for confirmation of email. So only after email confirmation, user gets registered. At the time of clicking forgot password, no need to check confirmation email of user.

Comment: I check the file of  devies.en.yml, how can I use the "signed_up_but_unconfirmed".. I want it to display in my view

Comment: I think you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122817/customize-the-devise-signed-up-but-unconfirmed-message

Comment: For that forum, it only change the message.. I want is how can I display the please continue and so on.. only after the registration